# How to drop array in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a response from an API call like below

```
    {
        "1-2021": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "status": "New",
                "player_count": 7
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "status": "Verified",
                "player_count": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "status": "Regitered ID",
                "player_count": 18
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "status": "On Playing",
                "player_count": 15
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "status": "Finished",
                "player_count": 9
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "status": "Active",
                "player_count": 10
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "status": "Inactive",
                "player_count": 0
            }
        ],
        "2-2021": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "status": "New",
                "player_count": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "status": "Verified",
                "player_count": 8
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "status": "Regitered ID",
                "player_count": 17
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "status": "On Playing",
                "player_count": 11
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "status": "Finished",
                "player_count": 7
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "status": "Active",
                "player_count": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "status": "Inactive",
                "player_count": 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

Then, I need to remove array value when **status "Inactive"**

My question is, what is the best way to do getChartData() to remove array value when status **"Inactive"**?.

Here my code :

```
getChartData(dataResponse) {
  if (dataResponse) {
    const dataChart = [];
    Object.keys(dataResponse).forEach((e, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        const b = dataResponse[e].map(r => r.status)
        b.unshift("Month")
        dataChart.push(b)
      }
      const a1 = [e]
      dataResponse[e].forEach(c => {
       a1.push(c.farmer_count)
       c.status
      })
      dataChart.push(a1)
    })
    this.chartData = dataChart
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me on how to drop values from nested arrays?

Thanks and best regards, Dede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Array#filter` method.

For example,

```js
const filtered = dataResponse[e].filter(item => item.status !== "Inactive");
```